# border-image not displaying properly in safari

Tags: html, css, safari, border-image

I am trying to have top and bottom borders on a div using `border-image` but it's not displaying properly in Safari.

Here it is in **Chrome**, as I want:
[image]

and here it is in **Safari**:
[image]

html:

```
<body>
    <div class="wiggle">
        <h3>title</h3>
        <p>Loren ipsum dolor sit amaet</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.wiggle{
    width: 500px;
    border-width: 13px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-image: url(assets/wiggle-b.svg) 100% 0% 100% 0% repeat;
    -webkit-border-image: url(assets/wiggle-b.svg) 100% 0% 100% 0% repeat;
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please provide us the actual images of the border?

Comment: [Sure, here](http://timmacqueen.co.uk/chicken/assets/wiggle-b.svg)

Comment: Its working fine on my side, which version of safari you are using?

Comment: ah yes I was on an outdated Safari! Works fine on 10.0.2. Thank you, I shouldn't have assumed I was on the latest version.